# Laplace Transform Question...

Tags: laplace-transform, moment-generating-functions

I have this Laplace transform

$$B^*(s)=\frac{1-\frac{\mu }{\mu +s}}{s-\lambda +\frac{\lambda  \mu }{\mu +s}}$$

and I am trying to compute the moments.

When I take the derivative and then evaluate it at $s=0$, it is not determinable. I.e.,

$$\frac{d}{ds}\left[\frac{1-\frac{\mu }{\mu +s}}{s-\lambda +\frac{\lambda  \mu }{\mu +s}}\right]_{s=0} = \mbox{Indeterminate}$$

But, if I take the Inverse Laplace Transform, it exists...

$$[B^*(s)]^{-1}=e^{-t (\mu -\lambda )}$$

Question:

1. How do you take the derivative of $B^*(s)$ and evaluate the result at $s=0$?

Comment: Just multiply the nominator and denominator by $\mu+s$: $B^*(s)=\frac{1-\frac{\mu }{\mu +s}}{s-\lambda +\frac{\lambda  \mu }{\mu +s}}=\frac{s}{s^2+s(\mu-\lambda)}=\frac{1}{s+\mu-\lambda}$.  All derivatives at $s=0$ are defined.

Comment: Yes --- you are correct - Good Grief...I'm not not having a good day...Lol

Comment: No worries... most importantly, the problem is fixed )